# Switching Intents in AWS LEX

Tags: javascript, python

i made a health assessment bot in AWS. the bots just asks basic questions and the user replies with yes/no. i added a greeting intent so the bot can be more lively. now, i have no experience with lambda functions. i need a lambda function code that will take me to the next intent after the current one has been fulfilled. thank you. this is the code i tried using .

```
const source = intentRequest.invocationSource;

  if (source === 'FulfillmentCodeHook') {
    return Promise.resolve(intentRequest.sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', null);
  }
};
```